# how to load radio buttons dynamically and use check property in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a generic input field for radio button which i am gonna use in my project whenever i need radio button in reactjs so i want to know how to pass radio buttons dynamically so that the first element is checked by default and how to use the checked property in map function

```
render() {
    var self = this;
    return(
      <div>
      {
        self.props.options.map(function(option){
          return <label key={option[self.props.id]}><input type="radio" className={self.props.className}
          checked={?????} key={option[self.props.id]}
          onChange={self.props.onChange} value={option[self.props.name]} />{option[self.props.name]}</label>
        })
      }
      </div>
    );

  }
```

options is my array of objects which i am passing to the map function

Any help will be very helpful..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the state for this. Use this:

```
this.state={checked: 0}

onChange(i){
     this.setState({
         checked:index
     });
  }


render() {
    return(
        <div>
            {
                this.state.options.map((option,i)=>{
                    return <label key={option[this.props.id]}>
                                <input 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    className={this.props.className} 
                                    checked={this.state.checked == i? true: false}
                                    key={option[this.props.id]}
                                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this,i)} 
                                    value={option[this.props.name]} />
                                {option[this.props.name]}
                            </label>
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Check the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/039eq8bx/

Comment: wont' work, the first one will remain checked always

Comment: @dfsq i just gave him the idea how to check, didn't wrote the complete code. check the working example now :)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i just gave him basic idea to put the check, check the complete working solution, now happy :)

Comment: @MayankShukla in your fiddle, as soon as i click on other options the previous checked options remain checked.. but it should be unchecked

Comment: I was not commenting about your solution, i just mentioned that particular antipattern. And apparently you still don't get what I mean. Nevermind

Comment: @dfsq i am also a beginner, i will be very helpful if you explain little bit more :)

Comment: one think i want to tell you, since you are passing the updated check value to parent, so instead of using a state in this component pass the value from parent and use that value with radio button :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Yeah sure :)  but what are the cons if i pass the updated state to parent??

Comment: read this article https://hashnode.com/post/why-does-react-emphasize-on-unidirectional-data-flow-and-flux-architecture-ciibz8ej600n2j3xtxgc0n1f0 :)

Comment: i have the same issue but my array is coming from redux reducer as a props how can i make it work?

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can hold a state of checked index and init it to 0,
and on your onchange function change it to the selected index.

something like :

```
<div>
{ self.state.options.map(function(option,i){
      return <label key={option[self.props.id]}>
                 <input type="radio" 
                        className={self.props.className}
                        checked={i==self.state.checkedIndex} 
                        key={option[self.props.id]}
                        onChange={self.onChange.bind(this,i)} 
                        value={option[self.props.name]} 
                 />
                 {option[self.props.name]}
             </label>
      })
}
</div>
```

and on your onchange function

```
onChange = function(i) {
     this.setState({checkedIndex : i})
}
```